# .htaccess issue when trying to remove the www from subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

What I am trying to do is redirect every single page to one subdomain page using .htaccess.

I am doing that with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?calu\.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://angelin.calu.info/ [R=301,L]
```

And everything works fine, except for the thing that this subdomain accepts also www.angelin.calu.info which is wrong.

I need to redirect everything from www.angelin.calu.info to http://angelin.calu.info. I have done several tries with no luck whatsoever. The result in all of my tries was:

http://angelin.calu.infoangelin/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to keep the request uri. Use the following code (copied from somewhere; don't have the original source to give credit):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Edit:

I suppose you have something like the following code in your .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.calu\.info$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%1/$1
```

This needs to be removed

Comment: Same problem, http://www.angelin.calu.info redirects to http://angelin.calu.infoangelin/

Comment: You probably have conflicting rules in your `.htaccess`. I'll edit in what I think is somewhere in your .htaccess

Comment: right now, my htaccess contains only what you have suggested, nothing else.

Comment: It might be in your `httpd.conf` or in a `.htaccess` in any parent directory. (also: Don't use [R=301] if you are testing. It messes with browsers. Use a temporary redirect until you are sure it redirects right.)

Comment: it's a new, un-indexed domain name, I'm not worrying about browsers right now, I just can't get it right with this redirect.

Comment: Also, there is no parent directory. The .htaccess is in the root foder of the domain and it is the only one there.

Comment: What I am saying is that 'http://angelin.calu.infoangelin/' is not a valid url that can be created from the rewriterule I gave, because it can't even match my rule. I suppose an other rule is matching and messing up your url. It's either in `httpd.conf` or in a `.htaccess` in a parent directory of wherever your subdomain is located in your filesystem.

Comment: I doubt your subdomain is pulled from `/` on your server. It is somewhere under `/home/someuser/www/subdomains/angelin/` or something fancy like that. Check all parent directories in that path.

Comment: well, I have my .htacess in `/public_html/calu.info` and my website files in `/public_html/calu.info/angelin`. Should that be a problem?

Comment: Look through `/public_html/calu.info/.htaccess` if any rules are matching. My rule should be put before the rule that lets subdomains work. I think your rule for subdomains should have an added / somewhere too.

Comment: My .htaccess contains only your solution `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: If I navigate to your page, it works correctly. If it doesn't redirect to the right page for you, then that is probably caused by the `R=301` from previous attempts. Clear your browser cache and try again.

Comment: wait, you are saying that http://www.angelin.calu.info redirects to http://angelin.calu.info for you???

Comment: I don't know what restarting my laptop has to do with anything but now it also works for me. Also, I have cleared the cache again.

Comment: Most likely in-memory cache. If you would have used `[R]` during testing, you'll notice that any changes you make will be displayed immedeatelly, because your browser doesn't remember temporary redirects. Permanent redirects are... well... meant to be permanent, and therefore the browser safes time by not making the same mistake twice and going to the rewritten url immedeatelly.